# Sikuli automated test enviroment

Tags: standards, iso, sikuli

Does anybody has information about sikuli's certification?
For exaple does it stands for 50128, IEC 62279 or  ISO 26262 standards?

Or does it satisfy any other standard?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try the Sikuli official forum here: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RaiMan from SikuliX:

No standards apply at all - OpenSource as private hobby.
Use as is ;-)